# Wordpress login hack attempt after creating new page

Tags: wordpress, security

I've had repeated login attempts at my wordpress admin using usernames like 'user' 'admin'. etc before, and Wordfence's security plugin always blocks the ip and notifies me of it. Yesterday however, after creating a new directory to do some css practice 'mydomain.com/test' (don't know if this is good practice on a live site), I had a login attempt trying the username 'test' within minutes.

I'm very new to website management. How did someone see the added page so soon and should I be worried that there's so many login attempts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need reset your password use on phpmyadmin and change password to md5 and after this try to login. Or if u need check your site for security first pentest is by SaaS service like https://penteston.com and after this try to fix bugs.